# .Include() .Where() in Linq to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to find all active patients, those with `EndOfTreatment == null`.

The problem is that the relationship has a complex structure.

I'm not so good with these database diagram things, but I've made the following pictue, I think you will get the point:

[image]

My attempt so far:

```
var ans = ctx
    .PatientMap
    .Include(p => p.Doctor)
    .Include(p => p.Product)
    .Include(p => p.Institution)
    .Include(p => p.Doctor.TerritoryDoctorPanel
        .Where(dp =>
            (dp.Territory.PromotionalLine == p.Product.PromotionalLine) &&  // issuing
            (dp.Territory.Active == true)                                   // lines
        )
    )
    .Where(p =>
        (IDProduct == null || p.IDProduct == IDProduct.Value) &&
        (p.EndOfTreatment == null)
    )
    .ToList()
    .Select(p => new ActivePatientModel
    {
        IDPatient = p.ID,
        Observation = p.Observation,
        TreatmentPeriod = DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(
            (DateTime)p.StartOfTreatment, DateTime.Now
        ).Months,
        NameDoctor = p.Doctor.FullName,
        CodeDoctor = p.Doctor.Code,
        CodeInstitution = p.Institution.Code,
    })
    .ToList();
```

I searched a lot and the closest I got was [this answer from Moho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336822/6188402), which adapted would look like:

```
.SelectMany(p => p.Doctor.TerritoryDoctorPanel)
    .Where(dp => dp.Territory.PromotionalLine == /*p.Product.PromotionalLine*/)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
                                                // How can I reference p.Product here?
```

---

Resume:

- I need to get `Patients` treated by `Doctors` using some `Product` working in `Territories`. The relationship exists by `Product.PromotionalLine = Territory.PromotionalLine`.
- `IDProduct` is of type `int?`, thus: `(IDProduct == null || p.IDProduct == IDProduct.Value)`

I'm really out of ideas how to make it work.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Are you just grouping all of this data, or do you have an actual product id or territory id, or both, that you are using to get back an exact set?

Comment: @TravisJ. It is a `JsonResult` and takes in `(int? IDProduct = null)`, see my last point.

Comment: @TravisJ. I see your point. I'm just grouping in this case, it is an Admin report, so I don't use any territory id or doctor id here.

Comment: Might I suggest you try starting with a `DoctorMap` (if you have one) instead of `PatientMap`, it would make more sense if you have such complex conditions relating to Doctors and where they work. Moreover, getting a list of Patients will become easier if you start with Doctors since there is a direct link ("doctor has many patients"). Basically, filter and select the right doctors, then just select a list of **those** doctors' patients. (You can use the Product filtering at the very end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try something, I hope I got your idea clearly though I am not sure I did.

so I guess your question is this

> I need to get Patients treated by Doctors using some Product working
>   in Territories. The relationship exists

and here is how i would do it.

```
var ans = ctx
    .PatientMap
    .Include(p => p.Doctor)
    .Include(p => p.Product)
    .Include(p => p.Institution)
    .Include(p => p.Doctor.TerritoryDoctorPanel
    .Where(p => 
        // some doctors, doctorIDs is list of all doctors id you want in case you are using id retrieval 
       doctorIDs.Contains(p.DoctorID) &&
       //working in some territory 
       //similar to this, you can filter any doctor Attribute 
       p.Doctor.TerritoryDoctorPanel.Any(t => /*Add condition for TerritoryDoctorPanel here */) &&
      (p.IDProduct == null || p.IDProduct == IDProduct.Value) &&
      (p.EndOfTreatment == null) && 
       // Product Promotion line conditions
       // also similar to this you can filter any product attribute 
      (p.Product.PromotionalLine.Any(pl => /*Add condition for promotional lines here*/)))             
    .ToList()
```

Comment: I changed the include to use `Territory` this way: `.Include(p => p.Doctor.TerritoryDoctorPanel.Select(dp => dp.Territory))` and in the part `t => /*Add condition for TerritoryDoctorPanel here */` I used: `dp => dp.Territory.PromotionalLine == p.Product.PromotionalLine`... I have to say: man, you rule!! It is working like a charm now :) ... Thank you !!! ... Just resuming, the lesson here is to combine `.Where()` with `.Any()` instead of `.Include()` with `.Where()`.

Comment: very happy to hear that 
Thank you and glad I helped :)